# Removing dropdown and text field from row removes incorrect field on State Change in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I have a row which includes a React-Select Dropdown and an input field. I am trying to Remove a specific row by its index. I am passing the index in my handler function and want to remove both the fields from the row. The input field is getting removed correctly, but the dropdown value is not getting removed from the same row and it deletes the dropdown from the last index.

I am removing the row with the help of index in this handler

**Removing the row by its index:**

```
handleRemoveSocial(idx) {
    let someArray = this.state.SocialData;
    someArray.splice(idx, 1);
    this.setState({ SocialData: someArray });
  }
```

I am rendering the Select Dropdown and Textbox with the help of map method, mapping to the array in my state. Now, How can i map the Select dropdown value from the same row when i remove the textbox. I have included the Sandbox link in this post.

```
{this.state.SocialData.map((Social, idx) => (
            <div className="form-group" key={idx}>
              <label htmlFor={"socialprofile"} className="control-label">
                Social profile
              </label>
              <div className="form-input-container select-social-link">
                <Select
                  data-id={idx}
                  className="profile-module-select-container"
                  classNamePrefix="profile-module-select"
                  options={options}
                  onChange={(selected) => {
                    this.handleSocialNameChange(selected.value, idx);
                  }}
                  onMenuOpen={() => {
                    this.setState({
                      selectMenuOpen: true
                    });
                  }}
                  onMenuClose={() => {
                    this.setState({
                      selectMenuOpen: false
                    });
                  }}
                  components={{
                    IndicatorSeparator: () => null
                  }}
                  placeholder={"Select"}
                  isSearchable={false}
                  isClearable={false}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="form-input-container input-social-link">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  id={`${SocialData[idx].socialname}-${idx}`}
                  className="social-form-control"
                  placeholder={`Social Url - ${Social.socialname}`}
                  value={SocialData[idx].name}
                  onChange={(e) =>
                    this.handleInputVlaueChange(e.target.value, idx)
                  }
                />
```

[SANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-pine-1xrsh?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where the problem is happening within `handleSocialNameChange()` Handler when `change` event is fired here.

```
onChange={(selected) => {
   this.handleSocialNameChange(selected.value, idx);
}}
```

Using index as ids is overall not a good idea. Because they mess up things later and we have to add additional logic to the code as well.

We can use `uuid()` library or a trick `new Date().getTime().toString()` for our Ids efficiently.

Working code of CODESANDBOX Link:

https://codesandbox.io/s/reasontosmile-n6ww4?file=/src/App.js

Enjoy :)

Answer (score -1):

You cannot set the `index` value as `key`. That will cause issues when adding and removing elements.
Also, don't use array.splice use array.filter. The `splice` will mutate the original state array.

Comment: I did use the filter method and used id instead of index. But still its not working...